# How to create a simple (Hello World) node.js TypeScript project with ES6 modules?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Imagine a very simple program with a main file and some functions in a separate file, using ES6 modules and intended to be run with node.js.

my-utils.ts:

```
import * as fs from "fs";

export function readSimpleFile() {
    return fs.fileReadSync("hello.txt", "utf-8");
}
```

main.ts:

```
import {readSimpleFile} from "./my-utils"

console.log(readSimpleFile());
```

What is the minimum set of files I need to add to the project and commands I have to run to get it building, running and checking types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are to run a typescript project with node you need to have at least node, npm and typescript installed on your plateform.

**Using an IDE to setup the project**

Using intelliJ IDEA or Webstorm (they are the ones I know the best), the compilation of typescript into javascript is done automatically; you only need to do some settings.

Let us assume you have a file called project.ts containing your hello world code; IDEA or Webstorm will compile your code to project.js. Then you will only need to do `node project.js` to run your project.

**Doing everything from scratch**

First you need to know where exactly your npm packages are installed globally. This command can help you identify the path: `npm config get prefix`. In this folder, you should have a `nodes_modules` subfolder that contains the typescript module. If there is no typescript module, that is because you did not install typescript globally (`npm install -g typescript`).

Then you have to add the path of the `bin of typescript subfolder` in your environment variable.

Now you can compile the project with typescipt: `tsc project.ts` and you can run it `node project.js`.

*Since you are using node function like `fs` you will need to install node typings `npm install @types/node --save-dev` before compiling with `tsc`.*

**Compilation option**

To enable or disable all strict type checking options, you might need to use compilation option. You have to create the file in which you will specify the compilation option: `tsc --init` will create a `tsconfig.json` in which you can specify what behaviour you would like to have during the compilation of your app. All options are listed [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Comment: `@types/node` was what I was missing, after installing that importing `fs` and using node builtins just works. :) I also found the `ts-node` package helpful: it has a slightly slower startup than plain `node`, but in case of error you get a useful traceback (with references to `.ts` files, not `.js` ones), plus there is no need to run `tsc` to execute the code that way.